# SSL issue when using custom domain as host for ActionMailer urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, dns, actionmailer

My Rails App runs on Heroku. We registered a custom domain with GoDaddy, but let our SSL be handled automatically by Heroku.

The bug occurs in the mailing process. In my `production.rb`file, I assigned `host = 'quouch-app.com'` which is the custom domain we registered with GoDaddy. It works for everything, but for the url creation in ActionMailer, e.g. when a user requests a reset password link, the created url wouldn't load and/or be tagged as not secure. Once I change it to the heroku subdomain `'quouch.herokuapp.com'`, I can access the page.

Any clue how to further investigate or why the SSL certificate error would not trigger anywhere else but when coming from an ActionMailer email?

I don't know if I have to set up something else like a DNS record. I currently only have the basic ones set up as MX records:

- smtp.gmail.com
- aspmx.l.google.com

Any input/documentation etc. appreciated. Thanks for your help.